# How Indicator constraint can be triggered with multiple variables in Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to write the constraint related to multiple variables. However, it shows error "Indicator constraints can only be triggered by a single binary variable at a given value". Can you help me fix this error? Thank you very much!
The code is following:

```py
mdl.addConstrs((x[i,j,k] - t[i,j,k] == 1) >> (d2[j,k] == d2[i,k] - d[i,j]) for i, j, k in arcos2 if i != 0 and j != 0)
```

Where:

- `x[i,j,k], t[i,j,k]` are binary variables
- `d2[j,k], d2[i,k]` are continuous variables
- `d[i,j]` is a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty clear. Define binary helper variables `q[i,j,k]` to represent `x[i,j,k] - t[i,j,k]`. Then:

```py
for i, j, k in arcos2:
    if i != 0 and j != 0:
        mdl.addConstr(q[i,j,k] == x[i,j,k] - t[i,j,k])
        mdl.addConstr((q[i,j,k] == 1) >> (d2[j,k] == d2[i,k] - d[i,j]))
```